# How to manually connect to resultsRepositoryConnectString from a load test .TRX file?

Tags: c#, database, load-testing, trx

In attempts to automate load testing in Visual Studio, I have run into problems with extrating the result data from the load test. I have a .TRX file which contains XML for the test, but no data. I am pretty sure that it connects to some database through the resultsRepositoryConnectString attribute in the XML. It looks like this:

```
resultsRepositoryConnectString="LAs4ogoKlDd+VpAl2ugknpVnps2Q+yFLesmD6LbUL+Km/JX8cBHGI53gZ4BH8pTCcqKm6fIrGHKGBGJ3QBDSWVtG/R9gmVK41LpMFWa4ySQbzsbWeWhaOim1CQqNS57+"
```

How should I go about interpreting this connection string? I am trying to open up a database connection in C# but I still need to specify attributes like the datasource and initial catalog.

Am I going down the right path? Thanks!

Comment: Not a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590088/546871 and the pages that that answer links to.

Comment: Open a ".loadtest" file in Visual Studio, then select "Manage test controllers" (from the context menu or the spanner command icon). The connection string is then shown, click on the adjacent ellipsis to get more details. This value must be saved in the ".trx" file but I do not know its format.